# Writing a function that uses for loop to replace the reporting values of one column in a dataset based on a character vector

Tags: r, function, indexing, data-wrangling

what I'm trying here is to build a function that I could run every time that I want to replace the reporting values in a dataset with their actual answer options.

Hypothetically, I the following answer options used to describe cars' colour:

`answer_options <- c("blue", "red", "yellow", "green")`

and then a dataset that contains the colour column:

`data <- data.frame(Animal=c("Parrot", "Pigeon", "Crocodile", "Impala", "Dolphin", "Dinosaur"), Colour=c(0,1,1,2,1,3), Year=c(2018, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2024))`

I have looked into every relevant question in here but can't find a way to make the following function replace the reporting values with the corresponding answer_options (Please note that I could replace them alternatively but my mission is to build a function and not have to repeat blocks of code every time):

```
answer.option.replacer <- function(dataset, column_index, replacer_vector, replacer_length){
for (i in 0:replacer_length){
dataset[[column_index]][dataset[[column_index]]==i] <-replacer_vector[i+1]}
return(dataset[[column_index]])
}
```

Now if I run:

`answer.option.replacer(data, 2, answer_options, 4)`

It prints the wished column with the values replaced but it doesn't actually replace them in the data. Any help would be really appreciated since I'm not very experienced with functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can just use the index to create the columns.  In `R`, the index starts from 1, so add 1 to the 'Colour' column and use that to replace values

```
data$Colour <- answer_options[data$Colour +1]
```

Comment: :o Thanks a lot.